# using RavenDB for Bulk inserts of data

Tags: twitter, ravendb, large-data, bigdata

I am trying to import large amounts of data (Twitter stream at about 20-25 tweets a second) into RavenDB for testing and large scale data testing. I have some code which is writing data quite well, but after a while I get an error:

[image: Error while trying to add lots of data to RavenDB]

I won't fill in all the code, but here is the gist of it:

```
Open RavenDB Session
Start reading data from Twitter Stream
For each line, parse JSON into known C# object
add item to RavenDB
increment counter
if counter % 25 = 0, save changes to RavenDB.
```

I have not tried what it has suggested, because it says to look at different ways of doing this. Should I kill my session every 200 or so inserts? Is there a way to insert an array of objects with Raven DB? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code where you "add item to RavenDB?"

Comment: It's really just session.store(item)... Don't have the code close to hand, but not doing anything weird... As I mentioned, when thecounterreaches a multiple of 25, I do a savechanges()...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two option:

- create a new sessions berefore the limit is reached (25 requests per session is a good value)
- increase DocumentSession.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequests to an appropriate value

Either way will work, although the second approach is *slightly* faster.

**Edit: According to Orens comment below, it is actually the first approach that is faster.**

Comment: Increasing MaxNumberOfRequests would result in a session that has a lot of entities, that isn't going to perform well. A new session is better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ayende. How often should the session be killed and recreated? 100? 200? More? Less? thanks!

Comment: @TiernanO, just make sure you dispose/re-create the session before you hit the request limit (by default = 30).